# multiple div with same class but display only ones with image inside

Tags: jquery

Please, i know that probabily this is a really easy question, but no matter what i try i can't make it work. I have few divs with the same class on my page, and i would like to show only divs that have an image inside. Can someone help please?

```
<div class="one">
   <div class="two"><img src="some.jpg" /></div> <!-- show this -->
   <div class="two"><img src="some_other.jpg" /></div> <!-- show this -->
   <div class="two"></div> <!-- hide this -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:has` selector:

```
$('.two').hide().filter(':has(img)').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Traversing up from images

You could base your selector on the images themselves, and from there traverse back up to the parents and toggle their visibility. One way would be to use the [`$.fn.parent` method](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```js
$(".two img").parent().show();
```

[image: flame chart]

This approach is fairly quick, taking just under 3ms for me. The above demonstrates the execution path.

### Filtering a collection

Alternatively, you could select all of the `.two` instances, and then filter that collection based on the presence of `img` elements using the [`$.fn.has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) function:

```js
$(".two").has("img").show();
```

[image: flame chart]

This method is a bit more involved, judging by the flame chart above, and took roughy 5ms compared to the quicker alternative above. You could alternative use the pseudo-selector `:has`, however this would mean you could no longer take advantage of performance optimizations that leverage [`querySelectorAll`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors_api/querySelectorAll).

### Show Some, Hide Others...

The above approaches assume `.two` elements are hidden initially. If this is not the case, the following could achieve this for you:

```js
$(".two").hide().has("img").show();
```

This approach selects all instances of `.two`, hides them, filters that selection to only those that have an `img` element among their children, and show's the resulting set.

*Flame charts based on jQuery 2.0.2 in Chrome 32*

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly easy with straight JavaScript not to mention a lot faster:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.two');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var self = images[i];
    if (!self.childNodes[0]) {
        self.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/CnnE5/)